# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with' creating a table, but im not using WITH

Tags: sql-server

Incorrect syntax near 'ID_DIM_UBICACION'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

```
CREATE TABLE "DIM_UBICACION" (`

    [ID_DIM_UBICACION] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [COUNTRY_ID] [int] ,
    [COUNTRY_NAME] [varchar](120),
    [CITY_ID] [int],
    [CITY_NAME] [varchar](120)
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DIM_UBICACION] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    )
    (
    [ID_DIM_UBICACION] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

---

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: That's not MySQL, it looks like SQL-Server.

Comment: @juergend The error message looks like SQL-Server. MySQL doesn't have common table expressions.

Comment: Why do you say you're not using `WITH`? The second-to-last line has `WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ...)`

Comment: Yes, you are right is SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

If it is MySQL, here is the script that works:

```
CREATE TABLE `DIM_UBICACION` (
    ID_DIM_UBICACION int not null,
    COUNTRY_ID int ,
    COUNTRY_NAME varchar(120),
    CITY_ID int,
    CITY_NAME varchar(120),
    CONSTRAINT PK_DIM_UBICACION PRIMARY KEY (ID_DIM_UBICACION ASC));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma at the end of this line:

```
 [CITY_NAME] [varchar](120),
```

Comment: But the error doesnt appear there, is in the line of ID_DIM_UBICACION